# storing import data in zato Redis db

Tags: redis, zato

In zato.io I would like to create a service and periodically pull data from ERP.
Later on that data will be pushed from zato.io to another external system. 
Is it a good practice to store that data (temporarily) in zato.io's default Redis database or new instance of Redis should be deployed?

Answer (score 0):

yes using zato.io's Redis database is possible.